# CreateJS/Canvas text position changed after chrome version upgrade from 70 to 71

Tags: google-chrome, text, version, upgrade, createjs

Createjs text position changed after chrome version upgrade from 70 to 71. please guide me.

Comment: Same issue here.. All my production is (heavily) concerned. Do you have any solution yet?

Answer (score 6):

I didn't like the current proposed solutions (changing the lineHeight or the line count) because they're not very reliable with different fonts, styles and sizes ... so I rolled my own solution:

```
var cache = {}
createjs.Text.prototype._drawTextLine = function (ctx, text, y) {
    this.textBaseline = ctx.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
    if (!(this.font in cache)) {
        var metrics = this.getMetrics();
        cache[this.font] = metrics.vOffset;
    }
    var offset = cache[this.font];
    if (this.outline) {
        ctx.strokeText(text, 0, y - offset, this.maxWidth || 0xFFFF);
    } else {
        ctx.fillText(text, 0, y - offset, this.maxWidth || 0xFFFF);
    }
};
```

The **alphabetic** value of **textBaseline** is the most reliable crossbrowser and generally the standard nowadays.

When it's set to both the **Text** instance and the **CanvasRenderingContext2D**, we can call **getMetrics** and have **vOffset** of the font from the top of it's bounding box to its baseline.

Apply that offset to the fillText call and you generally get a decent rendering of the font. The cache is there for good measure to avoid re-measuring the metrics of the same fonts on every frame.

From the (limited amount of) tests I ran so far, it seems to be:

- pretty stable crossbrowser
- performance conscious
- very close to the expected font rendering (as seen in Animate) showing just some minor offsets at high font sizes

And yet, some fonts still sucks (ie. Poppins) but I suspect it's a "fault" of the font itself in this case.

---

Hopefully [@lanny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252916/lanny) will have an official fix in createjs soon, but there's no guarantee when that will be included in Animate sadly.

Comment: This is great! I can look at getting this integrated next week.

Comment: Nice, thanks man. You guys can probably integrate that way better than I did. Having to use it with Animate I had to find a minimal monkey-patch to apply from "the outside" ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is an intentional change in Chrome to bring it inline with the "correct" behaviour (which Firefox has had all along). [Here is more information](http://%20https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=607053). It looks like that Chrome 71 (and later releases) finally addresses that bug.

The only affected alignment is "top", which is the default. Here is a quick comparison between the two Chrome versions.

[image: chrome text alignment comparison]

We are considering a built-in solution in EaselJS since this is more impactful then when it was just Firefox that was the outlier.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be solved similarly by overriding "_drawTextLine" in the same Text.js class as described here: https://forums.adobe.com/message/10845543#10845543.

The actual problem with this issue is that different fonts classic, google or adobe (former typekit) behave differently. I am looking for a solution that would normalize font alignment regardless its type or nature.

See an example below. Browser Chrome version 71

Without fix it is

[image]

With _drawTextLine fix

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just patched it (only tested with my team and with the Open Sans font) by a simple check on the current user agent and forcing the count property to 0.2 (just tested it with the logic of 1.2 * lineHeight in mind, and it works) instead of 0. Basicaly it will just push down the text by 20% of the lineHeight property.

***Be careful, it's not an offical patch, it works for me but it's not battle tested.***

Add this code at the begining of the file src/easeljs/display/Text.js (thanks to [is.js](https://github.com/arasatasaygin/is.js) for the browser detection code):

```js
var userAgent = (navigator && navigator.userAgent || "").toLowerCase();
var vendor = (navigator && navigator.vendor || "").toLowerCase();
var isChrome = /google inc/.test(vendor) ? userAgent.match(/(?:chrome|crios)\/(\d+)/) : null;
```

And at the line 348, replace the next line:

```js
var maxW = 0, count = 0;
```

By this one:

```js
var maxW = 0, count = isChrome ? 0.2 : 0;
```

Of course i'm opened to suggestions and improvments ! :)

Thanks!